# Make global constexpr variable appear in doxygen documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm working on a C++ project that exposes a lot of global `constexpr` variables which form an important part of the interface. I've documented all of them like this

```
/** Computes the absolute value of the source values.

    Complex source values are transformed into real values. Unsigned integers remain unaltered.
 */
constexpr ExpressionChainBuilder<Abs> abs;
```

(see [here](https://github.com/sonible/VCTR/blob/31c22663940c56daf2c308ce9a6608845a7d837a/include/vctr/Expressions/Core/Abs.h#L130) for a bit more code context).

Now when running doxygen, a documentation for the class declared in the same source file is rendered but no documentation for that variable. I've tried out some configuration options but none of them were successful so far.

So my simple question is: How do I make those variables appear in the rendered HTML documentation?

Comment: Such constants should be `inline` to avoid ODR issues; does that fix this issue too?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are your settings that differ from the default settings (i.e. the results of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)?

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks for the `inline` heads-up. Changing that didn't fix the issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doxygen documentation [seems to have example](https://doxygen.nl/manual/examples/file/html/file_8h.html) precisely for that case. You need to document `\file` for the document generator to have something with what to associate your global variable.

Comment: Since it’s in a namespace, one should document that.

Comment: @DavisHerring thank you, documenting the namespace did the trick, wasn't aware that this had such side effects.